# Difference between :: and Nil types in Scala

Tags: scala, list, subclass

I am learning Scala and working with List and creating a list of string as follows:

```
val myList = List("Laptop", "Mouse", "Keyboard", "screen")
```

From the documentation, I got:

> an abstract class List in the scala package, which comes with two subclasses for :: and Nil

And from the class definition I got:

```
@SerialVersionUID(509929039250432923L) // value computed by serialver for 2.11.2, annotation added in 2.11.4
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}

@SerialVersionUID(0 - 8256821097970055419L)
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  override def isEmpty = true
  override def head: Nothing =
    throw new NoSuchElementException("head of empty list")
  override def tail: List[Nothing] =
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("tail of empty list")
  // Removal of equals method here might lead to an infinite recursion similar to IntMap.equals.
  override def equals(that: Any) = that match {
    case that1: scala.collection.GenSeq[_] => that1.isEmpty
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

But the documentation does not shows when is NIL object is created and when is :: subclass object is created.

What is the difference between the two and please suggest, when to use :: subclass and when to NIL subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `List(..)` syntax, the compiler will use `List.apply` defined in the companion object of `List`:

```
override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

You don't actually see the list creation because it is created generically due to the way the Scala Collection Library is defined.

The difference between `::` and `Nil` is that the former represents a linked list which has a head and a tail, and the latter represents the empty list which contains no elements.

We can also define a list using `::` and `Nil` directly:

```
val list = "Laptop" :: "Mouse" :: "Keyboard" :: Nil
```

Which gets translated to:

```
val list = Nil.::("Keyboard").::("Mouse").::("Laptop")
```

Where the `::` does not refer to the type `::`, but to the method on `List[A]`:

```
def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] = new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```